# How do I turn off ads in Digsby?

Tags: windows, instant-messaging, digsby

The latest version of Digsby now puts an ad at the bottom of the chat window.  I would find this tolerable if it would not **animate!**  I hate animated ads so much I turned off gif animation entirely, both in Firefox and IE.  What can I do about digsby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Uncheck the checkbox. You will need [build 86](http://blog.digsby.com/archives/1691) to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools - Preferences - Conversations

-uncheck box  "Support Digsby development by showing an ad in the IM window."

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want ads, a better solution might be to **drop Digsby**. I used it for a while, and it has some nice features, but ever since its inception, Digsby has been **[loaded with adware](http://lifehacker.com/5336382/digsby-joins-the-dark-side-uses-your-pc-to-make-money)**. The installer bombards you with offers to install adware and trial software, and the program itself ran distributed computing on users' processors (which the developers profit from). The developers have a bad track record, and this is just another step in their ongoing tactics of deceiving users and filling their product with unexpected adware.

If you want some alternatives, I would highly recommend [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/). It's free, open source software, without any advertising. It can do most of what Digsby can do, and plugins can add functionality. Another option is [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), which has some similar features to Digsby. It's also free, though not open-source.

Comment: You say "which the developers profit from" as though they shouldn't...! They have mortgages too ! I agree with you on the point about it being loaded with adware and the terrible installer though.

Comment: I believe that developers should be compensated for their time and effort, but doing so in an underhanded, sneaky way without letting users _opt in_ (instead doing it automatically and making them opt out) is wrong. There are thousands of other free software products out there whose developers get by without loading their product with adware, let alone using their users' CPUs for distributed computing without expressly asking permission first.

Comment: [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/download/) is now ad-supported unless it's paid for.